# copying php page and edit it

Tags: php

I'm not sure what my next step should be so I would really appriciate if someone could point me in the right direction. What I want to do is to be able to edit a php-page for example 'Pressmeddelande.php' found in:
http://newsletter.something.se/nyhetsbrev/Pressmeddelande/Pressmeddelande.php

in my admin page found at http://www.something.se/editPressmeddelande.php. My admin page consists of a WYSIWYG and this is where I would like the code from the newsletterpage to end up so I can edit it and then save a copy of it in my db.

So basically, my question is how do I go about copying the page into my my WYSIWYG.

Many thanks
Linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea (to have ability to edit php script from front-end interface), but, well, you can use either [fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) + [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) + [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) or [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get file contents

Comment: ok thanks,why is it a bad idea? What would you recommend me to do instead?

Comment: To work on ability to edit data, but not code. Right now I can find only 1 exception that'd be a reason to allow editing script file: you building online PHP-code editor. In other cases, you better store data apart from code and your code should be able to load and modify data and also manage access to this two functions (users can only read, administrator can read and write/update). Otherwise, you make a big gap in security of your site/system/whatever you writing. Take a look at some relational database like [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is that you want the contents of an external page. You want to slurp it in. You could use the fopen function and provide an url as filename: see http://php.net/fopen

The contents of the page will be loaded in a variable, which you can parse and save or directly save in the database.

Is this what you are looking for?